# How to find a practical part for a master thesis in IT (Blockchain)

Tags: thesis, computer-science

I am writing my master thesis in Computer Science. My topic will be related to the Blockchain. I have no problem finding theoretical research questions, that I am really interested in. But the thesis should include a small practical project, where I actually write code. It should be something that I can work on alone over the course of half a year and have at least a prototype finished by then.

I have difficulties getting help in this area from my professor and supervisor as they allow maximum liberty to choose what ever I want to do.

How do I go about to find a suitable project that relates to one of my theoretical research questions?

Comment: I don't think, any of academia.SE people here would be guiding you either if your supervisor can't. You should ask directly this question to your supervisor. (S)he should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You go around organisations and ask them about what they would be interested. Having a network is a huge benefit here.
- You look into the introductions of the academic papers. See what real-life problems are recent articles talking about.

Basically those two. It does not need to be that good of an application, because it is even customary that the applications are stupid (simple) in academia. Real-life has all those legal issues like information security, confidentiality and such that you may not wish to be bothered with.

EDIT: Also real-life corporations are extremely unwilling to reveal their data, but also the intent of entering a market. An academic version is not even nearly ready business. I have seen applied math papers about how well the food and wine work together done for chemical corporation. You can guess that the end-project the theory was made for had only a little to do with wine and food.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. That's what I have been trying already. I guess my problem is, that I don't want to implement a completely unnecessary application. Maybe I just need to start on the theoretical part and when I know more about the topic I will find more sensible application ideas.